# Impact of events in one dataframe have on the values of another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two very large dataframes of the following structure(s):
df1:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(18871, 18873, 18883, 18928, 
18950, 18961, 18962, 18963, 18967, 18969, 18970, 18971, 18974, 
18975, 18976, 18977, 18978, 18981, 18982, 18983, 18984, 18985, 
18990, 18991, 18992, 18996, 18997, 18998, 18999, 19002, 19003, 
19004, 19005, 19006, 19009, 19010, 19011, 19012, 19013, 19016, 
19017, 19018, 19019, 19020, 19023, 19025, 19026, 19027, 19030, 
19031, 19033, 19034, 19037, 19038, 19039, 19040, 19041, 19044, 
19045, 19046, 19047, 19048, 19051, 19052, 19053, 19054, 19055, 
19058, 19059, 19066, 19082, 19104, 19107, 19108, 19109, 19110, 
19111, 19115, 19143, 19166, 19167, 19170, 19171, 19172, 19173, 
19174, 19177, 19178, 19179, 19180, 19181, 19184, 19185, 19186, 
19187, 19188, 19191, 19192, 19193, 19194, 19195, 19198, 19199, 
19200, 19201, 19202, 19205, 19206, 19207, 19208, 19209, 19212, 
19213, 19214, 19215, 19216, 19219, 19220, 19221, 19222, 19223, 
19226, 19227, 19228, 19229, 19230, 19234, 19235, 19236, 19237, 
19240, 19241, 19242, 19243, 19244, 19247, 19248, 19249, 19250, 
19251, 19255, 19256, 19257, 19258, 19261, 19262, 19263, 19269, 
19270, 19271, 19272, 19275, 19276, 19291, 19292, 19293, 19296, 
19297, 19298, 19299, 19300, 19303, 19304, 19305, 19306, 19307, 
19310, 19312, 19313, 19314, 19317, 19318, 19319, 19320, 19321, 
19324, 19325, 19326, 19327, 19328, 19333, 19334, 19335, 19338, 
19339, 19340, 19341, 19342, 19345, 19346, 19347, 19348, 19349, 
19354, 19355, 19356, 19360, 19361, 19362, 19363, 19366, 19367, 
19368, 19369, 19370, 19373, 19374, 19375, 19376, 19377, 19380, 
19381, 19382, 19383, 19384, 19387, 19388, 19389, 19390, 19391, 
19394, 19395, 19396, 19397, 19398, 19401, 19402, 19403, 19404, 
18964, 18968, 19024, 19032, 19103, 19264, 19268, 18884, 18935, 
19060, 19061, 19068, 19102, 19165, 19278, 18907, 18919, 18942, 
18914, 18872, 18876, 18877, 18878, 18879, 18880, 18885, 18886, 
18887, 18890, 18891, 18892, 18893, 18894, 18897, 18898, 18899, 
18900, 18901, 18904, 18905, 18906, 18908, 18911, 18912, 18913, 
18915, 18918, 18920, 18921, 18922, 18925, 18926, 18927, 18929, 
18932, 18933, 18934, 18936, 18939, 18940, 18941, 18943, 18946, 
18947, 18948, 18949, 18953, 18954, 18955, 18956, 18957, 18960, 
19062, 19065, 19067, 19069, 19072, 19073, 19074, 19075, 19076, 
19079, 19080, 19081, 19083, 19086, 19087, 19088, 19089, 19090, 
19093, 19094, 19095, 19096, 19101, 19116, 19117, 19118, 19121, 
19122, 19123, 19124, 19125, 19128, 19129, 19130, 19131, 19132, 
19135, 19136, 19137, 19138, 19139, 19142, 19144, 19149, 19150, 
19151, 19152, 19153, 19156, 19157, 19158, 19159, 19160, 19163, 
19164, 19265, 19277, 19279, 19282, 19283, 19284, 19285, 19286, 
19289, 19290, 19311, 19331, 19332), class = "Date"), Value = c(-5.33417292743301, 
-2.52617494564308, -1.49324009324009, -17.0425444455863, -9.35793961841595, 
-11.8841517857143, -9.69152125451611, -10.5028364323984, -8.5025565123789, 
-7.38025700934579, -7.78238256870689, -8.17978487280178, -7.7131012583794, 
-6.41295139213209, -8.91708282295298, -8.71221652160492, -10.0680747922438, 
-11.9437278705109, -16.4053740896049, -20.3138418538824, -23.3452022125799, 
-28.1797446210017, -28.9915196362348, -22.7089976941569, -53.3396956436279, 
-12.4708793300343, -11.1787848605578, -11.2914868901427, -9.00403312503746, 
-5.26940458505923, -3.2678042007321, -1.80023400936037, -1.00480716704905, 
-2.57038505839299, -6.25052713783678, -4.13951632213265, -4.66916949663517, 
-5.80691219642381, -9.01403811889207, -8.76200989722116, -5.14415894039735, 
-4.49265067482651, -6.81002817489304, -5.00625312656328, -12.9697844076655, 
-16.4525949550594, 1.35574468085106, -11.14101743721, -10.3890230312036, 
-9.95399610136452, -10.7999731146659, -10.0551036897388, -8.00489963647858, 
-6.98869824910699, -5.52771977448319, -5.8565313387104, -10.6561639051647, 
-10.1591881404835, -10.5755809770487, -12.7858263854831, -12.4515269244669, 
-9.75300293620429, -10.6174887030093, -10.9297709205513, -8.62649503888442, 
-5.67639625979277, -7.76497565794115, -5.11864292912328, -4.15677111515569, 
-1.24773160858034, -13.3209387381896, -4.61524571133755, -2.7064391500322, 
-2.54590337369225, -4.7534422125529, -5.77741708660495, -9.54039920679418, 
-3.49263873159683, -6.37633384146341, -4.8018775807754, -5.92095982827354, 
-6.7982259326898, -8.14429721160882, -14.0318602941176, -15.7693341697285, 
-6.33099406742874, -6.02467779730522, -6.67451006984472, -5.78277734678045, 
-6.76536805011747, -5.30100480559197, -5.48448933319592, -3.07906668141104, 
-1.19141872046993, -0.986825656313108, -2.78210279591495, -1.85680436798187, 
1.15368964707724, 0.592389680247037, 2.09444444444445, 1.47565073474096, 
-3.77455441789913, -4.99841919285848, -4.54737286347331, -6.52210666135604, 
-12.4586229788041, -9.76655410805627, -10.1672813163265, -10.1071078030427, 
12.1093036008042, -6.27654856354408, -11.7451651977779, -9.69657142857144, 
-14.7645443406988, -13.8044752609797, -12.8212930202637, -10.7131114789657, 
-9.7502835651603, -9.12285518188058, -7.82418739307804, -7.37290867229471, 
-5.42488374865864, -7.16548962504551, -7.22640747577296, -5.67880989576978, 
-2.38449197860963, -4.98403249527278, -8.01237481293888, -8.92721143345521, 
-11.0038498048729, -7.91574019894676, -7.24256979885921, -13.0468491640639, 
-12.4842416971359, -13.1832300362112, -9.69594285190952, -11.8236710963455, 
-15.4970313957103, -16.001590401224, -23.0116940912636, -20.0316726652775, 
-15.7387646961417, 14.3248459700742, -33.9856294639016, -29.5890893667004, 
-24.5815039111784, 0.351626092151443, -12.4957158872518, -13.5265822044065, 
-15.8057934508816, -18.5712850985479, -19.0062351207346, -17.8759978712081, 
-30.248495829345, -33.496764540864, -32.9090642540002, -35.9095838866755, 
-39.0622059592264, -37.4053056372396, 30.4444623180246, -17.2843857072932, 
-10.2894505770196, -9.46059792738388, -10.9101340816963, -10.6768441621886, 
-15.8564689156004, -25.0377375363291, -23.491809908999, -16.0848675710594, 
-9.52203025543524, -9.57329945269742, -8.26118487113689, -8.77146105741898, 
-7.52932569974554, -7.51696981061316, -6.34114162627894, -4.169791026429, 
-8.65363440517035, -7.07429566797939, -6.04901960784313, -3.95286523637039, 
-4.57831931564948, -4.70401930472815, -4.58048473762432, -4.19802716367601, 
-4.8712225795747, 33.7199676963457, -8.38811297695784, -8.41675133350266, 
-7.95239554602104, -7.61540762007296, -7.36910990686483, -5.19474884165624, 
-6.40677640427848, -6.6880699933269, -2.50748947332091, -5.01177083333332, 
-4.96342420082369, -3.74379953975965, -4.39864864864864, -3.96323864499468, 
-3.64570892339191, -4.00421168284196, -4.32506635700066, -3.84347776249426, 
-3.98014059753953, -4.93978444946085, -2.00666607412675, -4.40675836944916, 
-4.67217558943196, -4.69624595469255, -4.93134138588684, -4.59980852082335, 
-3.79959344732751, -3.56417422281594, -3.72577039757304, -6.8438477254722, 
-6.90215521144616, 17.0278089071515, -8.69234350531171, -8.31160081053697, 
-6.48055612912106, -2.82488289917003, -1.97938846776255, -2.76711193952573, 
-3.57596324527513, -2.66680277664353, -2.76065192083818, -3.07607539874335, 
-9.19352066115703, -7.40534903692798, -20.9290200655884, -9.4949337142347, 
-1.67593031748771, -4.00032731786333, -12.9233908365795, -3.12797485406376, 
-4.58038461538462, -4.92624181954726, -1.64177861663151, 14.5233533882204, 
-3.43662848605578, -7.00163549013596, -22.4328399502006, -5.68106442090641, 
-10.4667593755607, -8.32068944589428, -7.5574384739845, -1.18996298205332, 
0.685336364575798, 0.683983218163869, -0.190581124472707, 0.40016858076072, 
-0.685425265972909, -3.23485727546995, -2.17232406175909, -4.03732694666745, 
-3.43151815181518, -4.09670641680863, -6.31686046511628, -8.351512347464, 
-8.85095265741279, -7.33867558133818, -8.51522800856061, -8.98040313549832, 
-21.688225290116, -7.97696621402419, -7.54824182322704, -6.15927894799952, 
-4.38810945273632, -4.66345711216818, -6.63357687936353, -6.46356517733763, 
-7.69505643096672, -8.85590341722938, -9.65988090292203, -7.41890982503365, 
-8.4019243496411, -9.20245522237875, -11.7157621602604, -15.8009129904372, 
-16.7188609056313, -29.5936953565184, -16.1899352493468, -14.6818673311081, 
-9.23683475995534, -7.2676923950379, -5.58227412415489, -6.1622267560478, 
-7.530241504595, -8.17124428752656, -6.35655475028349, -8.35745036021789, 
-8.91222072419106, -8.32131192161132, -8.17337013669821, -10.877467450651, 
-9.77258672063867, -11.2631774313289, -10.1360580092287, -7.70075269546349, 
-3.16698645907571, -2.38109087441594, -0.022514417531718, -1.08499335989376, 
-3.3854513350099, -13.1874976421323, -12.0737487121089, -6.16346335921227, 
-6.0325834936609, -8.26060968320382, -6.76706578585191, -9.52737443465841, 
-3.80397824702367, -4.72200198216056, -5.16157624343703, -7.23900280010839, 
-6.18115990990991, -2.1293152465275, -3.7406576456566, -3.66946114241044, 
-2.04129052515896, -0.222846441947564, -0.318394134689292, -2.16259885464958, 
14.1518376302798, -1.73382942186606, 0.100049115913557, -0.378155479059093, 
-0.588078533746669, -0.121356930514267, -2.06994937873907, -2.84085812981032, 
-4.51622825625796, -3.44699324686462, -6.08916034821679, -10.3705139175517, 
-7.18844523191799, -7.9430781129157, -5.99308878256247, -7.00972211589987, 
-3.268970347887, -0.549423136888057, -6.08099664736361, -2.04115579182029, 
-0.832810782197972, -0.916704322940202, -0.2527559897864, -1.11381138113811, 
-1.81908592321755, -2.61384042630849, -2.35869084475896, 11.992052157715, 
-2.80402835408022, -1.61877788005381, -2.68177518524358, -11.6975791772843, 
-20.9404339865207, -27.5328187051002, -29.4899791627202, -28.9357382364862, 
-30.3360181743081, -30.4065839909808, -32.100806252164, -34.963228894691, 
-36.3754188653083, -24.3521969489358, -7.1991154066672, -4.39962753162101
)), row.names = c(NA, -369L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000214068b1ef0>)
```

df2:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(19402, 19396, 19395, 
19389, 19376, 19374, 19367, 19362, 19346, 19339, 19333, 19332, 
19332, 19327, 19319, 19311, 19311, 19306, 19305, 19291, 19290, 
19284, 19283, 19277, 19276, 19270, 19269, 19262, 19242, 19241, 
19236, 19227, 19220, 19213, 19206, 19200, 19194, 19192, 19185, 
19178, 19171, 19151, 19150, 19136, 19129, 19123, 19122, 19102, 
19094, 19087, 19066, 19059, 19053, 19038, 19018, 19010, 19003, 
18968, 18962, 18947, 18941, 18934, 18933, 18933, 18926, 18920, 
18913, 18912, 18906, 18905, 18905, 18898, 18892, 18885, 18884, 
18878, 18877, 18877, 18871, 18863, 18856, 18850, 18849, 18842, 
18835, 18828, 18815, 18814, 18814, 18809, 18801, 18794, 18793, 
18793, 18787, 18786, 18786, 18780, 18780, 18766, 18765, 18765, 
18758, 18758, 18752, 18752, 18745, 18738, 18737, 18731, 18730, 
18725, 18724, 18724, 18710, 18709, 18703, 18702, 18702, 18696, 
18695, 18690, 18688, 18688, 18681, 18675, 18674, 18674, 18668, 
18661, 18660, 18660, 18654, 18653, 18653, 18648, 18640, 18639, 
18639, 18633, 18605, 18604, 18604, 18598, 18598, 18597, 18597, 
18590, 18590, 18584, 18583, 18583, 18578, 18578, 18577, 18570, 
18569, 18569, 18563, 18562, 18562, 18557, 18557, 18555, 18549, 
18548, 18548, 18542, 18542, 18541, 18541, 18536, 18536, 18534, 
18529, 18529, 18521, 18520, 18520, 18515, 18515, 18508, 18508, 
18507, 18500, 18499, 18499, 18494, 18493, 18492, 18492, 18486, 
18485, 18485, 18479, 18479, 18478, 18478, 18472, 18472, 18471, 
18471, 18465, 18465, 18464, 18464, 18458, 18458, 18457, 18457, 
18452, 18450, 18450, 18445, 18445, 18444, 18444, 18438, 18437, 
18437, 18436, 18436, 18430, 18430, 18429, 18429, 18424, 18424, 
18423, 18416, 18416, 18415, 18415, 18410, 18410, 18409, 18409, 
18403, 18403, 18402, 18396, 18396, 18395, 18388, 18388, 18387, 
18387, 18381, 18381, 18380, 18380, 18374, 18374, 18373, 18373, 
18368, 18368, 18367, 18367, 18360, 18360, 18359, 18359, 18354, 
18340, 18338, 18331, 18326, 18325, 18317, 18312, 18296, 18289, 
18282, 18275, 18270, 18268, 18247, 18241, 18235, 18233, 18226, 
18214, 18205, 18198, 18191, 18184, 18177, 18170, 18163, 18144, 
18142, 18128, 18121, 18114, 18100, 18093, 18079, 18072, 18065, 
18059, 18051, 18039, 18025, 18002, 17995, 17988, 17981, 17969, 
17961, 17953, 17948, 17941, 17918, 17913, 17904, 17877, 17871, 
17869, 17855, 17850, 17841, 17827, 17808, 17799, 17794, 17785, 
17780, 17764, 17751, 17736, 17731, 17715, 17708, 17702, 17688, 
17675, 17660, 17654, 17645, 17640, 17631, 17625, 17617, 17605, 
17596, 17591, 17584, 17577, 17554, 17549, 17542, 17540, 17513, 
17507, 17505, 17491, 17486, 17479, 17463, 17458, 17449, 17444, 
17436, 17428, 17422, 17401, 17386, 17379, 17372, 17366, 17353, 
17344, 17339, 17323, 17318, 17309, 17304, 17290, 17282, 17276, 
17268, 17260, 17253, 17247, 17239, 17234, 17227, 17220, 17212, 
17206, 17204, 17197, 17184, 17178, 17176, 17171), class = "Date"), 
    Amount = c(3000, 2000, 3500, 3000, 1195.925, 4440.75, 3702.5, 
    3500, 3619.25, 3749.999, 744.65, 4062.498, 2812.5, 2812.499, 
    3559.5, 3250, 2250, 4374.998, 2750, 3500, 898.85, 4062.5, 
    3125, 4365.25, 1106.299, 3749.999, 2500, 1200, 3437.5, 4183.157, 
    2499.999, 750, 2803.5, 1760, 2771.875, 700, 4366.249, 2500, 
    3437.5, 2378.75, 1011.975, 3125, 3075, 847.7, 2187.499, 2500, 
    2250, 2499.998, 3124.998, 3250, 1239.4, 1874.999, 3250, 2250, 
    600, 3124.998, 3000, 1875, 2250, 2170.375, 900, 2500, 3000, 
    1533.75, 2750, 2812.5, 567.4, 1562.5, 3125, 3000, 2288.125, 
    2000, 350, 2857.916, 3000, 1010.725, 3250, 1250, 2859, 3000, 
    2274.25, 705, 3437.499, 2000, 3000, 1562.5, 701.05, 3437.499, 
    1866.25, 4232.497, 500, 3118.75, 3055.281, 2000, 1172.438, 
    3742.497, 1562.5, 3437.499, 2500, 3093.749, 4062.495, 2812.499, 
    3283.75, 1500, 2750, 2000, 1113.65, 3124.999, 4062.498, 713.825, 
    1000, 3437.5, 3394, 2000, 357.25, 2250, 2500, 4375, 1633, 
    878.975, 2812.5, 3437.5, 3147.351, 1562.499, 2499.998, 2500, 
    3250, 1250, 2000, 3143, 3000, 1071.25, 1036.3, 2936.25, 1750, 
    3250, 375, 3000, 1450.624, 3749.999, 3011.102, 4029.372, 
    2500, 1250, 2750, 3669.355, 2250, 3002.75, 1562.499, 2500, 
    4062.499, 2500, 3749.999, 1562.499, 861.4, 3000, 3405.625, 
    2499.999, 3084.999, 3510.742, 1249.999, 2632, 1986.875, 697.049, 
    3125, 3000, 1562.499, 2500, 884.149, 3518.452, 2000, 3250, 
    2000, 3437.499, 3749.999, 1310.749, 3124.999, 2867.5, 2187.5, 
    3250, 2421.749, 3412.749, 2500, 459.05, 2750, 3000, 1342.375, 
    1374.999, 3437.5, 4062.497, 2477.25, 3437.499, 3250, 1250, 
    2750, 562.25, 4062.499, 2812.499, 3500, 3008.875, 3437.499, 
    1874.999, 3000, 500, 3749.999, 2711, 3250, 1500, 3834.095, 
    3750, 1062.85, 3750, 2812.5, 4261.195, 2329.25, 3000, 2785.999, 
    1229.576, 3250, 1768.25, 3250, 3628.75, 4260.749, 2812.5, 
    3716.25, 2000, 3250, 4036.624, 900, 3941.249, 1500, 3328.75, 
    3749.999, 2927.5, 2357.75, 3750, 1785.499, 1562.499, 2500, 
    3869.624, 3250, 2250, 745.85, 3897.958, 1750, 4062.499, 3000, 
    3616.375, 2152.5, 1499.999, 3749.999, 3671.476, 3141, 4062.499, 
    1874.999, 3648.75, 2499.998, 3676.249, 2313.749, 2750, 2092.5, 
    4062.5, 1562.499, 2299.997, 3250, 2299.999, 2587.488, 1244.238, 
    3500, 3441.975, 3269.875, 800, 2750, 2545.872, 3250, 1056.037, 
    3162.497, 3162.496, 500, 2082.45, 3162.498, 3449.922, 2356.675, 
    2820.25, 1100, 3449.997, 3162.499, 919.998, 2250, 574.995, 
    2750, 3000, 1264.997, 2299.997, 3000, 3162.497, 2250, 3373.097, 
    2250, 3162.499, 700, 3000, 1437.496, 3000, 2250, 3135.1, 
    3449.998, 325, 1724.998, 3414.749, 1254.571, 1688.5, 2587.497, 
    2012.498, 2799.403, 2563.87, 500, 2012.499, 2500, 555.065, 
    2299.997, 2250, 1100, 3000, 872.72, 2750, 2500, 3000, 1100, 
    2500, 2750, 2299.997, 2874.995, 2587.495, 1381.4, 2750, 1146.874, 
    2810.081, 3427.034, 750, 2500, 2185.16, 2750, 675.24, 2864.731, 
    2250, 2815.66, 950, 2562.68, 1000, 2500, 2250, 2587.497, 
    800, 2276.5, 2750, 1000, 2722.32, 2750, 650, 2599.24, 2500, 
    3162.5, 950, 2500, 2500, 3158.628, 1000, 2250, 2500, 3162.498, 
    2867.806, 1000, 2587.498, 2874.999, 2500, 882.3, 2962.15, 
    2293.788, 857.793, 3162.497, 1724.999, 2867.739, 2874.999, 
    2299.997, 2557.917, 833.737, 2500, 2299.997, 1250, 2624.29, 
    3004.215, 2444.046, 2881.949, 2250, 837.798, 2329.914)), row.names = c(NA, 
397L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to work out the percentage impact the events listed in the second dataframe (df2) have on the values from the previous day entry listed in the first dataframe (df1). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi alex22. Can you elaborate on what "percentage impact" means? You could add an example of the calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve by:

```
df3 <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "Date")

df3<- df3 %>% arrange(Date) %>% mutate(percent_change = (value/lag(value)-1)*100)
```